# Usage of reference that has not yet been initialized

Tags: c++

Having the following small example, which is obvious not working, because the used reference has not yet been initialized when used.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Test {
  int MyCopy{myRef};
  int& myRef{myNumber};
  int myNumber{50};
};

int main()
{
  Test myTest;

  cout << myTest.MyCopy << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Why is the compiler not throwing any warning about the problem? Enabled all possible warning levels in g++ (-Wall -Weffc++ -Wextra). Can the compiler not recognise the problem?

Comment: its initalized to reference myNumber

Comment: FWIW Clang does catch this: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3E3cdzbor

Comment: You often need to [enable optimisations](https://godbolt.org/z/5Ev9bsTT6) in order to catch bad flow errors (though nothing is guaranteed of course).

Comment: Oh this is really interesting. So its possible for the compiler to recognize the problem. Thanks for the info!